# Can't Open a File I Just Created?

Tags: c, linux

I'm creating a module that deals with I/O operations in C.

MyIo.c

```
int MyOpen (char* f) {
    int fd = open(f, O_RDWR | O_CREAT, 777);
    return fd;
}

void MyClose (int fd) {
    close(fd);
}

char* MyRead (int fd, char* buf, int len) {
    read(fd, buf, size);
    return buf;
}

void MyWrite (int fd, char* buf, int len) {
    write(fd, buf, size);
}
```

MyTest.c

```
void ReadTest() {
   int fd = MyOpen("./a.txt");
   printf("%d\n", access("./a.txt", F_OK));
   if (fd < 0) printf("Error");
   // More Stuff
}


void WriteTest() {
   int fd = MyOpen("./a.txt");
   // Some Write Suff
   MyClose(fd);
   ReadTest();
}
```

Note that a.txt does not exist when the code is run.

The write test works fine; it creates a.txt and fills it with what I had written there.
The read test fails despite the fact that access says the file exists. The output is

```
0
Error
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You have a bunch of syntax errors: `cha*`, missing `)` on the `printf` line. Please post the actual code, don't retype it.

Comment: The permissions argument to `open()` should be 0777 to make it a base 8 literal. 777 in base 10 is a completely different set of permissions.

Comment: If you want to know why a system call fails, use `perror()` to print the message associated with `errno`.

Comment: Or better yet `|` together the symbolic constants like `S_IRWXU`. (Though I don't know why you'd want to include execute permissions or make it world writable)

Comment: Good catch, but shouldn't that also affect `WriteTest()`?

Comment: But make sure you call `perror()` before you call `access()`, as it may overwrite `errno`.

Comment: @Shawn Yes that solved my problem. With 0777 permissions everything works!

Comment: @Barmar No; the mode/permissions don't apply to the descriptor returned by `open()`, just to later use of the created file.

Comment: Note that `MyRead()` should return the number of bytes read rather than the pointer to the buffer passed in to be filled.  Similarly, the `MyWrite()` function should probably return the number of bytes written, though that will usually (but not always) be the same as the number of bytes requested to be written.  And both functions should use the `len` that is passed in rather than the undefined variable `size`.  There is a case to be made for using `size_t` instead of `int` for the lengths.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is the permissions in `MyOpen()`.

Decimal `777` corresponds to octal `1411`. The permissions part of this is equivalent to `r----x--x` -- the file is read-only to the owner, and execute-only to the group and others.

When you try to open it again in `O_RDWR` mode, this fails because you don't have write permission to the file.

Use `0777` to specify the permissions in octal.

You might want to consider having separate functions in your library for opening for reading and opening for writing.

Answer (score 0):

Use 0777 instead of 777 as 777 is decimal while the former is octal. Hope that helps!

Comment: How is this different from the answer from 2 days ago?